# Functor that automatically deduces return and parameter types

Tags: c++, templates, c++03, c++98

Say you have a common workflow that is often repeated, but with some variation:

- lock a mutex
- perform some actions
- unlock the mutex

I'm trying to achieve a mechanism that can automatically do this for arbitrary actions (in C++98). For instance, the following:

```
myMutex.acquire();
int a = foo(arg1, arg2, arg3);
myMutex.release();
return a;
```

Might become:

```
return doMutexProtected(myMutex, foo, arg1, arg2, arg3);
```

Or some similar mechanism. The challenge is with how to do this for arbitrary types of `a` and arbitrary types and numbers of arguments.

I have a sense that there should be a way to do this with templates, but am not sure how to accomplish it. You can do something similar with functors, but you must tell functors their parameter types ahead of time - I'm hoping for a way to have them detected automatically from the original function being called. That way, if (when) the function's parameter list changes, you do not have to update anything but the parameter list you are calling with.

Is this possible?

Comment: So you have to do this in C++98/03?

Comment: [Parameter packs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) were designed and added in c++11 for this purpose. This is very easy to do in c++11 or later. The hack for earlier c++ versions generally has you choose an arbitrary maximum number of arguments and implement a type/overload for each number of arguments. Type deduction though has always worked in c++ (as far as I know).

Comment: @NathanOliver unfortunately I'm constrained to C++98/03 for now. But I would love to know how to do this regardless, even in more do this in more recent versions of C++!

Answer (score 6):

In modern C++ (C++17) the function would look something like

```
template <typename Mutex, typename Func, typename... Args>
decltype(auto) doMutexProtected(Mutex& mutex, Func&& func, Args&&... args)
{
    std::unique_lock lg(mutex);
    return std::forward<Func>(func)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

This locks the mutex in a RAII type so all exit path release the mutex and then perfectly forwards the function and it arguments returning the exact type `func` returns.

Now, since you can't use modern C++ we have to try and implement as much of what the above does as we can and there are a couple way you could approach the problem. Implementing `std::unique_lock` is pretty trivial.  Depending on what features you want it can be as simple as

```
template <typename Mutex>
class my_unique_lock
{
public:
    unique_lock(Mutex& mutex) : mutex(mutex) { mutex.lock(); }
    ~unique_lock() { mutex.unlock(); }
private:
    Mutex& mutex;
    unique_lock(unique_lock const&); // make it non copyable
};
```

So that cover 25% of the problem :).  Unfortunately that was the easiest part.  Since C++98/03 doesn't have `decltype(auto)`, or even `decltype` or `auto`, we need to come up with a different way to get the return type.  We could make it `void` and use an output parameter, which would mean you don't need to specify anything when you call the function but this means you cant get a reference to what is returned.  At the cost of having to specify the return type you want you could have the function like

```
template <typename Ret, typename Mutex, typename Func, typename Arg1>
Ret doMutexProtected(Mutex& mutex, Func func, Arg1 arg1)
{
    my_unique_lock<Mutex> lg(mutex);
    return func(arg1);
}
```

and you would call it like

```
T foo = doMutexProtected<T>(mutex, func, arg);
T& bar = doMutexProtected<T&>(mutex, func, arg);
```

Since C++98/03 doesn't have variadic templates you are left with having to add a bunch of overloads to this for different amount of arguments and you'll have to decide at which point enough arguments is enough, i.e:

```
template <typename Ret, typename Mutex, typename Func, typename Arg1>
Ret doMutexProtected(Mutex& mutex, Func func, Arg1 arg1) {...}

template <typename Ret, typename Mutex, typename Func, typename Arg1, typename Arg2>
Ret doMutexProtected(Mutex& mutex, Func func, Arg1 arg1, Arg2 arg2) {...}

template <typename Ret, typename Mutex, typename Func, typename Arg1, typename Arg2, typename Arg3>
Ret doMutexProtected(Mutex& mutex, Func func, Arg1 arg1, Arg2 arg2, Arg3 arg3) {...}
...
```

and then you have to deal with references.  The modern version perfectly forwarded everything (nothing is copied unless that is what is required by `Func`).  We can't do that in C++98/03 so we have to add all of the reference permutations there are so we don't make unnecessary copies like the first version does.  That means

```
template <typename Ret, typename Mutex, typename Func, typename Arg1>
Ret doMutexProtected(Mutex& mutex, Func func, Arg1 arg1)
```

actually needs to be

```
template <typename Ret, typename Mutex, typename Func, typename Arg1>
Ret doMutexProtected(Mutex& mutex, Func& func, Arg1& arg1) {...}

template <typename Ret, typename Mutex, typename Func, typename Arg1>
Ret doMutexProtected(Mutex& mutex, Func const& func, Arg1& arg1)  {...}

template <typename Ret, typename Mutex, typename Func, typename Arg1>
Ret doMutexProtected(Mutex& mutex, Func& func, Arg1 const& arg1)  {...}

template <typename Ret, typename Mutex, typename Func, typename Arg1>
Ret doMutexProtected(Mutex& mutex, Func conts& func, Arg1 const& arg1)  {...}
```

and this is going to balloon as you add more parameters.

If you don't want to do all of this yourself, I believe [Boost](https://www.boost.org/) has done at least some of this work for C++03 and you can use their utilities.

Comment: Very complete answer! Shame to see how easy it is in recent versions...one can only dream. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much for providing a solution for C++17, this is exactly what I was looking for. This also fixes the issues I was having then using an `std::function` argument instead of a plain template argument for the passed function. I managed to use your solution to implement a `forEach(Func&& func, Args&&... args)` function that locks the object mutex while applying a callback on each element in my thread-safe container.

Answer (score 1):

Let me take your example literally:

> For instance, the following:
>
> ```
> myMutex.acquire();
> int a = foo(arg1, arg2, arg3);
> myMutex.release();
> return a;
> ```

You should not be writing code like that in the first place. Why? It is not exception safe. What if `foo` throws an excpetion? You will miss to release the mutex and eventually your program will wait forever for a mutex that never gets released.

The way to avoid that is to use [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization), aka: "destructors are your friend". If you cannot use C++17 which has `std::scoped_lock` you can easily write your own scoped lock and you can even use a template to do that:

```
template <typename mutex_t>
struct my_scoped_lock {
     mutex_t& m;
     scoped_lock(mutex_t& m) : m(m) {m.acquire();}
     ~scoped_lock() { m.release(); }
};
```

Now you cannot forget to release the mutex:

```
int foo( /*...*/ ) {
    my_scoped_lock<mutex_t> lock(myMutex);
    int a = foo(arg1,arg2,arg3);
    return a;
}
```

If you want to know how to write a function you are actually asking for I refer you to the other answer, I would just suggest you to reconsider if it is really worth the effort.

> Or some similar mechanism. The challenge is with how to do this for
>   arbitrary types of a and arbitrary types and numbers of arguments.

Maybe this "other mechanism" is simply writing a function as I indicated above.

PS: I was going to extend this answer, but in the meantime there is already an answer more complete than I could provide, so I'll just leave it fwiw.

Comment: +1 for suggesting RAII, it's a good point given how I phrased things. It was not necessarily intended specifically for resource acquisition/release though, but more for anything that follows the pattern of "do something constant, then do something unique, then do something else constant". However, depending on the code you are writing, your point may still exist!

Comment: @Oracular i had the feeling that your are overcomplicating the matter for the given example. As I understood the question your example isnt really the best for what you want to write, so I decided to concentrate on the example first and then I realized that there is already an exhaustive answer before I could get to the core of your question

Comment: @Oracular btw RAII is more general than one might think. A "resource" can be anything. Eg you can write a class that does "something constant" in its constructor and then "something else constant" in its destructor, now you simply have to create an instance of this class at the beginning of the scope where you "do something unique"

Answer (score 0):

Once you have a `scoped_lock` as suggested by other anwers, you do not need a functor anymore. You can write your example like this:

```
return scoped_lock<Mutex>(myMutex),
          foo(arg1, arg2, arg3);
```